# updateLocation is not a function

Tags: node.js, polymer

I'm following [this](https://web-font-and-copy-changes-dot-polymer-project.appspot.com/2.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods) example to create an element and call its method. I'm doing:

```
class streetViewCard extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'street-view-card';
  }
...
updateLocation(coordinates) {
//empty for now for testing
  }
...
customElements.define(streetViewCard.is, streetViewCard);
```

And then using this element and giving it and id of `streetViewCard`, then getting this element by:

```
this.streetViewCard = document.querySelector("streetViewCard");
console.log(streetViewCard); //this logs the element to the console OK, it's NOT null
streetViewCard.updateLocation(feature.geometry.coordinates);
```

And this gives an error `Uncaught TypeError: streetViewCard.updateLocation is not a function`. Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, the update from `console.log(streetViewCard)` is:

```
class streetViewCard extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'street-view-card';
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      title: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Street V…
```

Comment: can share the console output of `console.log(streetViewCard);`

Comment: @Sohaib sure I updated the question!

Comment: If you want to access by id you should use `document.querySelector("#streetViewCard");` otherwise use `document.querySelector("street-view-card");` and in console output you should see the element instead of class

Comment: I've tried adding an id to the element and then doing `document.querySelector("#streetViewCard");`, but I still only see the class on the console output.